# URL redirection within FOR loop PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, php-5.6

I have a `for-loop` in my PHP page that runs for 4-5 times. I have to add a URL-redirection within that loop so that the page it redirects to is accessed 4-5 times (every time with new `$_GET` value). But as soon I leave the page, obviously the state of `for-loop` is gone. I know session variable is a possible solution, but I want to know is there any better way of doing this?

The reason I want to re-direct multiple times is to call an API that in returns generates an image and saves in the directory. Every time I have to call a different URL (actually a different `$_GET` value) so that different image is generated upon every call.

Comment: Can you elaborate on why you want to do this? If you want to make a request to a page 4 or 5 times then a redirect isn't what you want - they, by definition, should take you to the target on the first request

Comment: Are you trying to fetch data for use in your script, or do you want the user to visit 4-5 websites?  You might want to look at curl (http://php.net/curl)